# How can I get pods by label, using the python kubernetes api?

Tags: python, kubernetes, label

I am using the python kubernetes api with [list_namespaced_pod](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#list_namespaced_pod) to get the pods in my namespace. Now I would like to filter them, using the optional label selector parameter.

The [documention](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#list_namespaced_pod) describes this parameter as

> A selector to restrict the list of returned objects by their labels.
>   Defaults to everything.

It does not bother to give an example. On [this website](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96328/kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api), I found several possibilities on how to use the attribute. I already tried

```
label_selector='label=my_label'
label_selector='label:my_label'
label_selector='my_label'
```

non of which is working. How do I use the parameter label_selector correctly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Kubernetes CLI uses two types of label selectors.

1. Equality Based
   Eg: `kubectl get pods  -l key=value`
2. Set Based
   Eg: `kubectl get pod -l 'key in (value1,value2)'`

`label_selector='label=my_label'`

should work, else try using

`label_selector='label in (my_label1, my_label2)'`.

If this does not work the error might come from somewhere else.

Comment: You were right. The correct way to do it is `label_selector='label=my_label'`. Error must have been somewhere else

Answer (score 15):

this works for me:

```
v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace='default', label_selector='job-name={}'.format(name))
```

Comment: The selector is actually `job-name`, not `job_name`

Comment: I think that yours is the actual answer to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

(Python client) This works for me and it returns JSON

```
result = v1.list_namespaced_pod( "default", label_selector="label_key=label_value",watch=False)
print(len(result.items))
```

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan's Answer shows how to add the OR condition.

If we want to add the AND condition. here is the code

```
label_selector='app={0},tier={1}'.format('app_name', 'backend')
```